# One UIPickerView with multiple textfields

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Can I use one UIPickerView with many UITextFields, or should I create many pickerviews, one for each UITextField (I have all the UITextFields in the same view)?

Comment: if you got your answer then tick right click given with answer

Comment: ok but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Click on the tick mark next to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one Picker view with multiple textfields would be enough. You can easily tag the textfields and process them according to your needs.

[Multiple sources for UIPickerView on textfield editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324510/multiple-sources-for-uipickerview-on-textfield-editing)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/12952-tutorial-uipickerview-basics-basic-tip-calculator.html

Will help you get started

Comment: thanks for your answer. how i can accept your answer , please ?

Comment: Just click on the tick mark to the left of the answer to turn it to green

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField1.editing == YES)
    {
        textFieldName=textField1;
    }
    else
        if (textField2.editing == YES)
        {
            textFieldName=textField2;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Array list view and then get the position.

Answer (score 2):

Please declare this textFieldName globally:

```
NSString * textFieldName;
```

Allocation in didLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [pickerView setHidden:YES];

    textFieldName=[NSString alloc]init];

    pickerArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple", @"mango", @"banana", nil];

    pickerArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"black", @"white", @"green", nil];
}
```

Please set text field name in textFieldName string:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [pickerView setHidden:YES];
    if (textField1.editing == YES)
    {
        textFieldName=textField1;
        [pickerView setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
        if (textField2.editing == YES)
        {
            textFieldName=textField2;
            [pickerView setHidden:NO];
        }
    }
```

Then use this textFieldName to check in the pickerview method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    if (textFieldName isEqualToString:@"textField1")
    {
        return [pickerArray1 count];
    }
    else
        if (textFieldName isEqualToString:@"textField2")
        {
            return [pickerArray2 count];
        }
    }

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    if (textFieldName isEqualToString:@"textField1")
    {
        return [pickerArray1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
        if (textFieldName isEqualToString:@"textField2")
        {
            return [pickerArray2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (textFieldName isEqualToString:@"textField1")
    {
        textField1.text= [pickerArray1 addObjectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
        if (textFieldName isEqualToString:@"textField2")
        {
            textField2.text= [pickerArray2 addObjectAtIndex:row];
        }
        [pickerView setHidden:YES];
    }
```